# PostgreSQL update table with join value

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables like following

```
Table Fruit
-- id,
-- colorIds[]

Table Color
-- id
-- name
```

In `Table Fruit`, I have following records

1. `(1, [1, 2])`

In `Table Color`, I have following records

1. `(1, 'Red')`
2. `(2, 'Green')`
3. `(3, 'Black')`

Now I want append color `Black` to record `(1, [1, 2])` so it would be `(1, [1, 2, 3])`.

I tried with following SQL in `PostgreSQL` but seems not working. Any advice? Thank you very much!!!!

```
update Fruit f
set f.colorIds = f.colorIds || c.id
from Color c
where f.id = 1
and c.name = 'Black'
```

Comment: [works just fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=226c157cf183787b4d4fdaa10ac5c822) (after fixing `set colorIds`)

Comment: thank you! works for me as well after change `set f.colorIds` to `set colorIds`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [array_append](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html) function, which adds an element onto the array. That is:

```sql
UPDATE Fruit f
SET f.colorIds = array_append(f.colorIds, c.id)
FROM Color c
WHERE f.id = 1
AND c.name = 'black';
```